# how can i make this image slider show an image without having to press the dots or buttons? it only shows arrows and dots first

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

I got this source code from "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp" and when it first shows after each time I click refresh on the page, only the dots and arrows appear, so I was wondering how I can make it so it appears on an image first hand.

When you first add the code to a text editor and link all the HTML, CSS, JS, and open it in the browser, all you get is the arrows and the dots. After you click on either of those the image appears and it works nicely. But after each refresh the same problems appears 
 Just want it to make it so the image appears automatically.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].